# iOS: Three20: TTTableItem Delegate: How to identify tableItem uniquely?

Tags: ios, three20, selector, uniqueidentifier

(I posted the question below on the Three20 forum, but [no response so far](http://forums.three20.info/discussion/474/tttableitem-delegate-how-to-identify-tableitem-uniquelys)! Maybe you guys can help out.)

I use the TTTableViewController in my iOS app and there is one thing I wish to achieve.

Each of the TTTableItem classes has a method to assign a delegate & selector when initializing it.

Eg: TTTableTextItem has (+itemWithText:delegate:selector:) Now, the selector method would hav a signature like this: -(void)selectorMethodForTableItem:(id)sender; I would like to identify uniquely the tableItem that was selected, but within the selector method I only have the TTTableTextItem object, which only has the 'text' parameter. (The 'text' parameter is a string and it could be the same for 2 tableItems)

I can easily solve this if I provide a TTUrl for each tableItem, but I do not want to navigate to a new screen when a tableItem is pressed. Just say, I want to display an alert based on which tableItem a user selects.

How do I solve this problem? Do I have to define a custom TTTableItem class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set a TTURL for each of your `TTTableTextItem` and "catch" the touches in the `TTTableViewController`, before `TTNavigtor` takes over, so your app won't navigate to a different page.

in your `TTTableViewController`, add this function:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)didSelectObject:(id)object atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  TTTableItem* item = object;
  NSLog(@"%@", item.URL);

  [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Note this function doesn't call the parent `didSelectObject`, meaning it won't pass the object to the `TTNavigator`.

Comment: Simple and effective. Thanks!